# usecols in pandas read_table results in "list index out of range"

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select just 2 columns when parsing some data with pandas.

The help of `pd.read_table` mentions a `usecols` option that seems to be exactly what I want:

```
usecols : array-like, default None
    Return a subset of the columns. All elements in this array must either
    be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or strings
    that correspond to column names provided either by the user in `names` or
    inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a valid `usecols`
    parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']. Using this parameter
    results in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.
```

My data, once read, appear to have columns numbered from 0 to 6:

```
In [338]: pd.read_table("../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/intersect_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt", index_
     ...: col=3, header=None)[:3]
Out[338]: 
                0      1      2  4  5    6
3                                         
WBGene00022277  I   4118  10230  -  .   83
WBGene00022276  I  10412  16842  +  .  230
WBGene00022278  I  17482  26781  -  .  303
```

But when I try to keep only the index (column 3) and the last one (column 6), I get the following error:

```
In [339]: pd.read_table("../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/intersect_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt", index_
     ...: col=3, header=None, usecols=(3, 6))[:3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-339-279bef505f16> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_table("../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/intersect_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt", index_col=3, header=None, usecols=(3, 6))[:3]

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    644                     delim_whitespace=delim_whitespace,
    645                     as_recarray=as_recarray,
--> 646                     warn_bad_lines=warn_bad_lines,
    647                     error_bad_lines=error_bad_lines,
    648                     low_memory=low_memory,

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    387         kwds['encoding'] = encoding
    388 
--> 389     compression = kwds.get('compression')
    390     compression = _infer_compression(filepath_or_buffer, compression)
    391     filepath_or_buffer, _, compression = get_filepath_or_buffer(

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    728 
    729                 if dialect_val != provided:
--> 730                     conflict_msgs.append((
    731                         "Conflicting values for '{param}': '{val}' was "
    732                         "provided, but the dialect specifies '{diaval}'. "

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    921         for arg in _deprecated_args:
    922             parser_default = _c_parser_defaults[arg]
--> 923             msg = ("The '{arg}' argument has been deprecated "
    924                    "and will be removed in a future version."
    925                    .format(arg=arg))

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1445                 cast_type = dtypes
   1446 
-> 1447             if self.na_filter:
   1448                 col_na_values, col_na_fvalues = _get_na_values(
   1449                     c, na_values, na_fvalues)

/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _clean_index_names(columns, index_col)
   2812                 msg = ('Expected %d fields in line %d, saw %d' %
   2813                        (col_len, row_num + 1, actual_len))
-> 2814                 if len(self.delimiter) > 1 and self.quoting != csv.QUOTE_NONE:
   2815                     # see gh-13374
   2816                     reason = ('Error could possibly be due to quotes being '

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I had successfully used the `usecols` option in another case, but with some headers kept from the original file.

**What is causing the problem here ?**

#### Edit: `header=None` is apparently not the problem

I can parse a differently-formatted file, without keeping headers, and the `usecols` option works:

```
In [361]: pd.read_table("../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/feature_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt", skiprows
     ...: =2, index_col=0, header=None, usecols=[0, 6])[:3]
Out[361]: 
                  6
0                  
WBGene00022277   72
WBGene00022276  222
WBGene00022278  302
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here but could it be because you're already using column 3 as the index. Did you try to only `usecols=[6]`?

Comment: In the previous case where I used `usecols`, I included the index and it worked. Here, even with just `usecols=[6]` I get the "list index out of range".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like it has to do with the `index_col`

Try setting the index after reading the file:

```
path = "../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/intersect_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt"
df = pd.read_table(path, header=None, usecols=(3, 6)).set_index(3)[:3]
```

Apparently `index_col` is being used after reducing the columns. You're selecting two columns and then try to select the third one as index.

```
path = "../RNA_Seq_analyses/mapping_worm_number_tests/hisat2/mapped_C_elegans/intersect_count/W100_1_on_C_elegans/protein_coding_fwd_counts.txt"
df = pd.read_table(path, header=None, usecols=(3, 6), index_col=0)[:3]
```

Comment: This works, but why can I set the index while reading with another file (see edit) ?

Comment: @bli Added explanation

Comment: Thanks, the explanation makes sense.